# Is it possible to define a dynamic grammar (created with PHP) for a speech input field?

Tags: html, input, inline, grammar, speech

Is it possible to define a dynamic grammar (created with PHP) for a speech input field?

See http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html.

I would like to do this inline (added to my HTML with PHP) but I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question here: [HTML5 Speech recognition --- is there a way to set what the user is expected to say dynamically? (Using custom Grammars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848979/html5-speech-recognition-is-there-a-way-to-set-what-the-user-is-expected-to?rq=1)

I do not know if any Google Chrome supports using custom grammars, but if it does that is how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

currently speech-input is available in limited html5 compatible browsers... like google chrome

```
<input type="text" id="search" value="" x-webkit-speech />
```

use this to enable speech recognition for input boxes (works in google chrome). also speech controlling is done on client side. only the processing may be done on server side (to get what the client said in the voice )

Comment: like in the following example: 
 <input speech grammar="grammar-nav-en.grxml" onspeechchange="handleSpeechInput">
They used an grxml grammar to tell the server some possibilities, I would like to do that, but dynamically with php, any chance you know more about such a case?